# Re-ordering messages with discord bot

Tags: discord.py

I am writting a bot and i want to work out how to efficiently re order old messages.

For example

the sequence of messages on a channel where only the bot posts, or commands are given to a bot might be

```
Bot: "1"
Bot: "2"
Bot: "3"
Bot: "4"
Bot: "5"
```

Then the user uses the command $cycle

I want the messages on the channel to then read

```
Bot: "2"
Bot: "3"
Bot: "4"
Bot: "5"
Bot: "1"
```

[I'm not writing the users comand in the aove snippet as there are a few things you could do with it - but I'm most interested in what we are doing with the bots message sequence]

I can see a couple of ways of doing this, but as discord [limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits) the rate at which you can post an edit messages, I'm not sure which would be most efficent.

The bot could edit each message - but that would hit their speed limit. Alternately could send the messages again - but that would also hit their speed limit. Ideally it would be nice to edit the order they are placed in but this appears not to be allowed by the API.

Here is a bot command that you can use to generate a sequence of messages like the above.

```
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='type a sequence of words seperated by spaces and they will be repeated back to you as a sequence of messages')
async def repeat(ctx, *lines):
    print("repeating")
    await asyncio.gather(*[ctx.send(line) for line in lines])
```

Here is my attempt at making a cycle command

```
@bot.command(name='cycle', help='help me to understand bots')
async def cycle(ctx):
    #prepare to read in the most recent sequence of messages from the bot
    message     = ctx.message
    channel     =message.channel
    messages    = []
    #read them in
    async for other_message in channel.history(before=message, limit=1000):
        messages.append(other_message)
        if other_message.author.name!= bot.user.name: 
            break
    #missing code
```

The above reads in the messages so you can edit them into the new order, resend them in a new order or do something else. What would the fastest implementation of the cycle command be?

Comment: So you're wanting to repost old bot messages in a varying order?

Comment: you could also edit the old messages or there may be another way - I want to find the fastest way